# In emacs, how do I bind C-l to clear screen in slime?

Tags: emacs, common-lisp, slime

Is there a way to bind C-l in SLIME to clear the screen?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you probably want is `slime-repl-clear-buffer`, which is by default bound to `C-c M-o`. You can bind the function on the Slime REPL buffer in the normal way, for example

```
(local-set-key [(control l)] 'slime-repl-clear-buffer)
```

Comment: I tried your method as well as



  
  `(add-hook 'slime-mode-hook
      '(lambda()
          (local-set-key (kbd "C-l") 'slime-repl-clear-buffer)))` but neither seem to work.

Comment: Well now it works but I don't know why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

@nosefouratyou the problem with the add-hook was that you need to add it to the 'slime-repl-mode-hook instead of 'slime-mode-hook:

```lisp
(defun my-slime-keybindings ()
  "For use in `slime-mode-hook' and 'slime-repl-mode-hook."
  (local-set-key (kbd "C-l") 'slime-repl-clear-buffer))

(add-hook 'slime-mode-hook      #'my-slime-keybindings)
(add-hook 'slime-repl-mode-hook #'my-slime-keybindings)
```